# Proof that Any two linear maps from a $1$-dimensional vector space to itself commute

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

I was attempting a different exercise and thought about this question. Would appreciate if someone could check if the proof is correct.

Proposition: Let $V$ be a $1$ dimensional vector space. Prove that any two linear maps $S, T\in L(V, V)$ commute.

Proof: Suppose that for any two arbitrary linear maps $S, T$ we have that $ST\ne TS$. Using the theorem that every linear map from a $1$ dimensional vector space to itself is a scalar multiplication by some scalar, we see that there exists a scalar $\lambda \in F$ such that $S(u)=\lambda u$. Substituting this into the inequality $ST\ne TS$ we see that $\lambda T(u)\ne T(\lambda u)$. Using the linearity of $T$ we see that $\lambda T(u)\ne \lambda T(u)$. Which is a contradiction. Hence, any two linear maps $S,T\in L(V, V)$ commute.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: The proof is correct and doesn't need changes. Your cited theorem is the most important here,

Comment: It's not clear whether the inequalities are supposed to be true for at least one $u$ or for all $u$,  which makes this proof unclear. I think it would be more straightforward if you didn't use proof by contradiction.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC My bad, I should have added that it is supposed to hold for all $u$. I thought when we wrote just the maps without referencing the variables, that would imply that we are talking about all the elements in its domain.

Comment: No, the proof is not correct. When you negate, you don't know that *all* pairs fail to commute — just one particular pair.  But I would recommend ditching the proof by contradiction and just doing it all directly.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh yeah. Should have thought about that. The proof in the answer below would be the ideal way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @TedShifrin Kind of a redundant question. But would changing the hypothesis to: For all $u$ suppose that $ST \ne TS$. This will work right. Although I realised it is much easier to prove by a direct proof.

Comment: No, you still only know that $ST(u)\ne TS(u)$ for some particular $u$. You need to work on your quantifiers and negations.

Comment: @TedShifrin Got it, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but "for all $u$ suppose that $ST \ne TS$" will not work right. Honestly, it's not even really a sensible mathematical statement. I agree with @TedShifrin - your "negating 'for all' statements" and "what it means for functions to not be equal" need work. Do you have a TA, professor, or tutor you could go over your work on this problem with?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC yeah I figured that. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC If this annoying, you don’t have to answer. But I think I figured out why my proof is wrong. I was originally trying to negate the statement $“ST= TS$ For all $u$. The negation of this would “there exists a $u$ such that $(ST)u\ne (TS)u”$. And this approach fails. Then the negation of my statement in the comments would be “There exists a u such that $(ST)u=(TS)u$”. Which is not what I wanted to prove. So I see how all of my proof was wrong. Thanks to you and Ted Shifrin, this was a nice lesson!

Comment: The statement of the proposition is "Any two $S, T$ in $L(V,V)$ commute.". Keeping in mind that $S$ and $T$ are functions, the fully qualified equivalent is "$\forall S \forall T \forall v, S(T(v)) = T(S(v)) $. So, to negate that you use DeMorgan's law for quantifiers three times to get "$\exists S \exists T \exists v$ such that $ S(T(v)) \ne T(S(v)) $". I don't know about the rest of your proof, but if you want to do proof by contradiction that how you would start it. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof looks right, but this is how I would phrase it:

Let $S,T\in L(V,V)$ be arbitrary. By the theorem, there exists a scalar $\lambda\in F$ such that $S(u)=\lambda u$ for every $u\in V$. Now,
$$ST(u)=\lambda\cdot T(u)=T(\lambda\cdot u)=TS(u)$$
for any $u\in V$, so $ST=TS$.

Comment: That's a nice way of phrasing it as well!

Comment: Your proof is correct, but the OP's proof does not look right. I don't think you're doing them any favors by ignoring the problems it has.